# Why it says ValueError for the below program with python3 but not python2

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, hashtable

```
k=['d','e','f']
v=[4,5,6]
h=zip(k,v)      #zipping
for i,j in h:
  print(i ,':',j)
(k,v)=zip(*h)   #unzipping
print(k)
print(v)
output:

Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "hasht.py", line 6, in <module>
    (k,v)=zip(*h)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

zip creates a list in Python 2, so your `h` is a value that you can inspect at any time.  zip creates an iterator in Python 3, so your loop with the `print` statement exhausts `h`.

Use `h = list(zip(k, v))` to get the same behavior in both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
k=['d','e','f']
v=[4,5,6]
h=zip(k,v)      #zipping
zip_list=list(h)
for i,j in h:
  print(i ,':',j)
type(h)
h
```

## Here your zip is now empty in python 3.x. Hence the error

```
(k,v)=zip(*h)   #unzipping on empty object
print(k)
print(v)
```

You can still iterate on zip_list object created multiple times

```
for m,n in zip_list:
   print (m,n)
```